# How to toggle between ibus and xkb?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, ibus

I am using MX GNU/Linux v19 (Patito feo). I have installed these three packages with `apt`.

1. ibus
2. ibus-mozc
3. ibus-anthy

I can confidently say that they got installed correctly as I can see this in the Japanese section of ibus-preferences.

[image: 1]

I can see the ibus icon in my panel too!

[image: 2]

but I still can't input Japanese. It is still using my xkb keyboards. So in this case How to temporarily switch to ibus?

I wanted to know if there is any commands for fully activating **and** fully deactivating ibus? I would need both of them as I very often need to switch to my xkb-layouts too. I am planning to add keyboard shortcuts for both of those commands which I believe will make my life very easy :)

GUI solutions are welcome as they will be useful for other users having similar issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have also posted this question [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1416771/866251).

Comment: Please read site rules; questions can only be asked on a single Stack Exchange site. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: Sorry, I have deleted the other post, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not toggle between xkb and ibus. You fully switch to ibus - it will support both multi-key and single-key languages.

Not sure how it is done on MX GNU, but in Debian derivatives there always an "Input Method" section in the settings, where you do a complete switch to ibus, fcitx, xim, etc (the option "none" there would a switch back to xkb).

Once you install `ibus` package, you should have a tool `ibus-setup`. It will allow you to set hotkeys to switch between layouts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have some custom keyboard layouts defined with xkb which I can't stop using. I am very accustomed to it now. Is there any way to customize ibus?

Comment: Of course you can make your own layout in ibus. Same `ibus-setup` will help. It also has an option 'use system layout' which is to use whatever layout there is if you disable ibus's layouts - in your case that would be custom xkb layout.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)